# How to split latitude and longitude separately

Tags: javascript, json, loops, split

I want to loop through the value of objects of an array that has latitude and longitude together as a value (but separated with a comma).

What I want to achieve is to split the latitude and longitude and store them separately like this:

[image: how it should be]

This is how my data looks like. The `key` I'm interested in is the `location`:

[image]

Comment: Where's the code you tried?

Comment: I think you should post your tried code and asked for where it goes wrong. Just not to ask anyone else to do your code here.

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `split` function on the string and pass the separator, which is `,`. You need to do this for each item in the array.

```
const coordinates = topDeals.map(item => { 
   const [latitude, longitude] = item.location.split(',');
   return { latitude, longitude };
});
```

Example of `split`

```js
const coordinates = '3.213213,5.3556';
const [longitude, latitude] = coordinates.split(',');

console.log(longitude);
console.log(latitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` and `map`

```
var markerCordinates = topDeals.map( s => {
   var location = s.location.split( "," );
   return { latitude : +location[0], latitude : +location[1] }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "key": "shdgujdbff",
  "location": "4.648580,7.935496"
},{
  "key": "jlterokkl",
  "location": "14.648580,45.935496"
},{
  "key": "weriojsd",
  "location": "31.648580,-9.935496"
}];

var arr = [];
for (var i in jsonObj) {
  var latlong = jsonObj[i].location.split(",");
  arr.push({"latitude": latlong[0],"longitude": latlong[1]})
}

console.log("Array", arr);
```